# Reading header data in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers

I am making an API where in the access token for Facebook login will be sent in through header data.

How do I read this data from the header?

Comment: Search keywords: "rails header request".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Exactly that led me here.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

```
request.headers["Content-Type"] # => "text/plain"
```

replace "Content-Type" with the name of the header that you want to read.

Update for Rails 4.2

There are 2 ways to get them in Rails 4.2:
Old way (still working):

```
request.headers["Cookie"]
```

New way:

```
request.headers["HTTP_COOKIE"]
```

To get a Hash with all headers of the request.

```
request.headers
```

Comment: Why are there old/new ways mentioning here at all? I don't find the "new way" documented as of today; better quote [the official source](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/Headers.html).

Answer (score 31):

Rails now attaches HTTP_ to the header as well as converting it to all caps so it would now be:

```
request.headers["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]
```

Comment: i have money that says rack does this not rails. could be wrong tho

Answer (score -12):

To get hash of actual **http** headers use `@_headers` in controller.

Comment: Accessing instance variables like this directly is really bad form. That underscore is there as a reminder to not do this.

Comment: As a general rule, any time you're accessing an instance variable that wasn't set explicitly in that class (or module)... you're probably doing something dangerous.