# Cross-Origin blocking AJAX connection with Google Maps even with the headers seted

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, cors

Well, I have a SSL domain calling for the Google Maps API.

```
function typed_address(str) {

            var url = 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+str;
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();           
            xhttp.open('GET', url, false);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                 if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    if (result.results[0]) {
                        latlng = result.results[0].geometry.location;
                        document.cookie = 'lat=' + latlng.lat;
                        document.cookie = 'lng=' + latlng.lng;
                        map.setCenter(latlng);
                        marker.setPosition(latlng);
                    }
                 }
            };  
            xhttp.send();
        }
```

When I do this request within my SSL domain, I have this on my browser console:

```
Blocked cross-origin request: Same Origin Policy prevents the remote resource from reading at https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=R.%20PROF.%20LOURIVAL 20% 20% 20% 20% 20% 20% 20% 20PE% 2055016-445. (Reason: 'access-control-allow-credentials' symbol missing in CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' header during CORS pre-connection
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=R.%20PROF.%20LOURIVAL%20VILANOVA%20-%20UNIVERSIT % 20% 20%, 20% 20% 20%, 2055016-445. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
NetworkError: A network error occurred.
```

And here below is what I get on Network debug:

[image: Network browser console]

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? It seems that it's not reading my request headers...

Comment: I think you may need to set the headers in php or whatever processor you are using?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header.  It doesn't make sense to set it on your AJAX request.  It would be like you telling someone, "Yes, you can totally trust me".  The response should be saying, "Yes, we trust the domain that is trying to get data from us".

Comment: I'm using Ruby on Rails 5.2, @atoms

Comment: Haha, got it. But whats should I do then, @zero298?

Comment: Have added a link to set headers in Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the headers when the webpage is output to the browser. Not in the ajax request. If your using php you could add sheaders

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
```

To set headers in Ruby see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729795/reading-header-data-in-rails)

Comment: For Ruby on Rails (Ready to use):

`request.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
      request.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "true"
      request.headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "1000"
      request.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding"
      request.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE"`